# How to configure Aptana RadRails plugin for Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, aptana, radrails

I just installed Aptana RadRails in Eclipse as a plug in. While I was in the RadRails perspective, I clicked 'New Rails Project' and gave the project a name and immediately received an error.

```
>rails MyNewProject -d sqlite3
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

It appears the aptana plugin is using Rails 2 syntax and not Rails 3 syntax. Rails3 requires the **new** keyword

How can I configure the plugin to use Rail3 syntax?

Answer (score 1):

From the discussions forums of aptana

> Studio 3 should work fine with rails 3. It looks in your script folder to see whether or not there is a script/server command in your project. If there is, it assumes its a rails 2.x project. Your rails3 script folder should just contain the 'rails' script.

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/438-rails-3-on-studio-3